# log4net crashes when called from Parallel operation

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a solution with working log4net, which is instantiated all over my app using Windsor Castle IOC framework. It works, accept for one case!

my architecture:

```
CoreLib
  ILogger
  Logger

WebLib
  web.config  (log4net settings)

MailServiceLib
  MailService
```

Offending code (inside WebLib):

```
MailService.Ctor() { _log = IoC.Resolve<ILogger>(); }
MailService.Send(...)
...
_log.Info("this always works..");
Parallel.ForEach(to, po, address => {
    _log.Info("BAP!!"); 
    _log.Info("KAPOW!!"); // <-- this works on first loop, but exists the process sometime after with no exceptions being caught or errors logged anywhere 
    ...
    client.Send(msg);
```

adding _log.info inside the loop, crashes the process somewhere down the line (on send i think). and exceptions are not being caught.

I also enabled log4net diagnostics (internal debugging), but nothing is written there, besides the usual stuff on start.

**update**

tired putting a lock around it, but no change to the behavior so far.

```
lock (_logLock) {
    _log.Info("sent");
}
```

Comment: What about the Event logs of the computer its running on? I'd say you'll have to throw a lock around it.. given that its probably logging to a file?

Comment: just a warning. 
iisexpress\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Clr4IntegratedAppPool is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled.
probably because iisexpress quit?

Comment: as far as i can tell log4net file logger is thread safe?

Comment: tired using a lock, but didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: [Log4Net Troubleshooting](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/) to the rescue!

Comment: @aleksey.berezan thanks but I already tried log4net internal debugging